# ale can't update the status line for golang

Tags: plugin-you-complete-me, plugin-ale

I've succeeded in configuring a vim-c++ environment based on the plugin YCM and the plugin [ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale).

I use YCM to do the auto-completion and ALE to hint me errors and warnings.

I added the config as below to update the status line:

```
set statusline+=%#warningmsg#
function! LinterStatus() abort
    let l:counts = ale#statusline#Count(bufnr(''))
    let l:fst = ale#statusline#FirstProblem(bufnr(''), 'error')
    let l:all_errors = l:counts.error + l:counts.style_error
    let l:all_non_errors = l:counts.total - l:all_errors
    return l:counts.total == 0 ? 'OK' : printf(
    \   '%dW %dE(%d)',
    \   all_non_errors,
    \   all_errors,
    \   fst.lnum
    \)
endfunction
set statusline+=%{LinterStatus()}
set statusline+=%*
```

It worked as expected.

For example, the c++ code as below will show `0W 1E(3)` at the status line.

```
int main()
{
    xxxx
}
```

Now I'm trying to configure a vim-golang environment with the plugin YCM and the plugin ALE.

I've built the YCM with the command `./install.py --go-completer`. For ALE, I used the same config as above and I add one line to configure golang:

`let g:ale_linters = {'go': ['gopls', 'golangci-lint', 'gofmt']}`.

However, the status line always show me `OK`, meaning that there is no error, no matter how I create an error.

[image]

As you can see, there does exist an error but the status line shows me an `OK`.

`:ALEInfo`

```
 Current Filetype: go
Available Linters: ['bingo', 'gobuild', 'gofmt', 'golangci-lint', 'golint', 'gometalinter', 'gopls', 'gosimple', 'gotype', 'govet', 'golangserver', 'staticcheck']
   Linter Aliases:
'gobuild' -> ['go build']
'govet' -> ['go vet']
  Enabled Linters: ['gofmt', 'golangci-lint', 'gopls']
 Suggested Fixers:
  'gofmt' - Fix Go files with go fmt.
  'goimports' - Fix Go files imports with goimports.
  'remove_trailing_lines' - Remove all blank lines at the end of a file.
  'trim_whitespace' - Remove all trailing whitespace characters at the end of every line.
 Linter Variables:

let g:ale_go_go_executable = 'go'
let g:ale_go_golangci_lint_executable = 'golangci-lint'
let g:ale_go_golangci_lint_options = '--enable-all'
let g:ale_go_golangci_lint_package = 0
let g:ale_go_gopls_executable = 'gopls'
let g:ale_go_gopls_options = '--mode stdio'
let g:ale_go_langserver_executable = 'go-langserver'
let g:ale_go_langserver_options = ''
 Global Variables:

let g:ale_cache_executable_check_failures = v:null
let g:ale_change_sign_column_color = 0
let g:ale_command_wrapper = ''
let g:ale_completion_delay = v:null
let g:ale_completion_enabled = 0
let g:ale_completion_max_suggestions = v:null
let g:ale_echo_cursor = 1
let g:ale_echo_msg_error_str = 'Error'
let g:ale_echo_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_echo_msg_info_str = 'Info'
let g:ale_echo_msg_warning_str = 'Warning'
let g:ale_enabled = 1
let g:ale_fix_on_save = 0
let g:ale_fixers = {}
let g:ale_history_enabled = 1
let g:ale_history_log_output = 1
let g:ale_keep_list_window_open = 0
let g:ale_lint_delay = 200
let g:ale_lint_on_enter = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_filetype_changed = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_insert_leave = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_save = 1
let g:ale_lint_on_text_changed = 'normal'
let g:ale_linter_aliases = {}
let g:ale_linters = {'go': ['gopls', 'golangci-lint', 'gofmt']}
let g:ale_linters_explicit = 0
let g:ale_list_vertical = 0
let g:ale_list_window_size = 10
let g:ale_loclist_msg_format = '%code: %%s'
let g:ale_lsp_root = {}
let g:ale_max_buffer_history_size = 20
let g:ale_max_signs = -1
let g:ale_maximum_file_size = v:null
let g:ale_open_list = 0
let g:ale_pattern_options = v:null
let g:ale_pattern_options_enabled = v:null
let g:ale_set_balloons = 0
let g:ale_set_highlights = 1
let g:ale_set_loclist = 1
let g:ale_set_quickfix = 0
let g:ale_set_signs = 1
let g:ale_sign_column_always = 0
let g:ale_sign_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_info = '--'
let g:ale_sign_offset = 1000000
let g:ale_sign_style_error = '>>'
let g:ale_sign_style_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_warning = '--'
let g:ale_sign_highlight_linenrs = 0
let g:ale_statusline_format = v:null
let g:ale_type_map = {}
let g:ale_use_global_executables = v:null
let g:ale_virtualtext_cursor = 0
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_blank_lines = 1
let g:ale_warn_about_trailing_whitespace = 1
  Command History:

(executable check - success) gofmt
(finished - exit code 0) ['/bin/bash', '-c', '''gofmt'' -e ''/tmp/vmCvq7C/1/test.go''']

<<<NO OUTPUT RETURNED>>>

(executable check - success) golangci-lint
(finished - exit code 3) ['/bin/bash', '-c', 'cd ''/home/zyh/tmp/src'' && ''golangci-lint'' run ''test.go'' --enable-all']

<<<NO OUTPUT RETURNED>>>
```

Comment: What put the sign there, ale or ycm?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  it should be `ycm`.

Comment: Ok. So what is `:ALEInfo` saying?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble I put the output in the question.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble In fact, I tried to use ALE without YCM, but it doesn't seem that ALE can do autocompletion, which means that I have to type `<C-x><X-o>` manually... So I mixed them up or what?

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  I've installed `golangci-lint` so `:ALEInfo` changed but this problem is still there. I've reedited my question. You can see at the end of `:ALEInfo`.

Comment: Ale is a linter with a few other features. Nothing to do with completion (though i’ve grown to prefer triggering it manually). If the linters aren’t returning any errors, then ale won’t show any. That said, i use `bufnr('%')` in my statusline code for ale.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble  Well, not working still, I give up..